# Are these terminal commands safe for installing Evolution 3.8.0?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, security, evolution

I run 12.04 and want to update my Evolution to 3.8.0. I found a solution and would appreciate help knowing whether it is correct and safe. Any better solutions are welcome. I have never compiled from source and am a beginner. Thanks

> To Install Evolution 3.8.0 in Ubuntu 13.04/12.10/12.04 and Mint
>   15/14/13 ,  open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following
>   commands in the Terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution/evolution_3.6.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i evolution_3.6.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb 
> sudo apt-get install -f
> ```
>
> If any error you can follow this command :
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install evolution
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are saying the same thing. The 1st method downloads Evolution manually from Ubuntu repos and then unpacks and installs the .deb file.

The 2nd method is about doing the above manual process automatically with APT.

If you use the 1st method you will have your cache file in the current directory of your terminal and if you use the 2nd method the cache will be in the apt cache directory. Otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: Apart from the fact that neither will install 3.8.0 ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As a matter of fact none the commands you proposed will install Evolution 3.8

### Installing from a `.deb` file

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution/evolution_3.6.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i evolution_3.6.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

These commands will download a .deb package and try to install it. Your example will download evolution **3.6.0**. The installation will probably fail due to [unresolved dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/104434/22537).

You can find more information on installing .deb packages on :

- [This Ask Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/22537)
- [The Ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_downloaded_packages)

---

`sudo apt-get install evolution` will do the same thing as installing evolution from the Software Center. For Ubuntu 12.04 this means installing evolution **3.2.3** (See [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/evolution))

---

### Installing from a PPA

Generally when you want to install software that is not in the Ubuntu repository or when you want to install an updated version of a package you would use a PPA.

- [Ask Ubuntu has a excellent Q&A on the subject](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

The Gnome team keeps a [PPA of packages](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) that did not make it into the main Ubuntu repositories. The most recent components of Gnome in Ubuntu 12.04 from the PPA are 3.4. Evolution 3.8 is available in the [gnome-staging ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging) in Ubuntu 13.04.

---

The only way to get Evolution 3.8 installed on Ubuntu 12.04 would be compiling it by hand, but you will probably encounter lots of problems with dependencies.